# APEX 5 set custom failed login message

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm using a custom login function resulting with a true/false value whenever the user should be allowed to login or not (a standard thing).
My problem is: when the function returns "false" the standard message is displayed "invalid login credentials"

[image]

even if the credentials are correct. Is there any chance to customize this message?
EXAMPLE: login function checks the credentials (ok) AND some additional, non relevant things (fe if the user is allowed to login into this particular application) (not ok) -> login = false -> invalid credentials message.
A small workaround that I know of is to raise a user defined exception in the login function but I'd like to omit that scenario as basically the run should be without errors (everything worked and was verified).

Comment: a small workaround that i know of is to raise a user defined exception in the login function but I'd like to omit that scenario as basically the run should be without errors (everything worked and was verified)

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a validation on your login page. Like this:

1. In Page Processing click on Create validation:

[image: 1]

2. Select Page as the validation level

[image: 2]

3. Name the validation and select 'Inline in Notification' as the Error display location

[image: 3]

4. Select PL/SQL as the validation type

[image: 4]

5. In this case I will create a validation to avoid the login until January 1st 2025, so I chose PL/SQL expression as the sub type of PL/SQL validation

[image: 5]

6. Enter the PL/SQL expression (it has to be a true/false evaluation) and the error message that will be displayed in case the condition return false.

[image: 6]

7. Select the login button and allways as the condition type

[image: 7]

And that's it. This validation will occur every time the login button will be pressed and return the custom message. [Here's a working example](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=91698:101:104044223758731:::::) try to login with any username or leave it blank and first will check the date condition.

[image: 9]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this idea's very cool (i'll vote it up asap), tho doesn't exactly answers my question. As I understand the INVALID_CREDENTIALS message is displayed whenever login function returns false and there is no way to change it

Comment: lets have 2 groups of user - one which can login and second one that can log in only after 2025. With the validation above, I'm able to check every user without even knowing his password if he's authorized to enter the application as the validation kicks in before the login process

Comment: @PrzemoS the idea is to evaluate additional user conditions through a validation instead of through a customized authentication scheme.

Comment: @PrzemoS yes you could do that too.

Comment: I've got a single authentication scheme used in dozens of applications. It checks: login credentials (1) and if user can use particular application(2). Only when both conditions are ok, the login function returns true else it throws the default message which is misleading as I don't know if the password was incorrect or the users is not authorized for the app. Also it shouldn't be possible to check app availability without knowing users password - that's why I'm not convinced wiith the validation you gave. Another thing - this validation should be defined for every single application :(

Comment: so for this scenario I can only see defining user exceptions which are throwed to api

Comment: @PrzemoS a validation doesn't replace an authentication scheme.